# ffmpeg does not respect FPS when using -f segment option

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I am creating a dashcam library where video files are written constantly to 2 buffers. When an event happens, the most recent buffer is returned. Everything works fine except when I try to customize the FPS, I see inconsistent behavior.

This is the ffmpeg command I use:

```
ffmpeg -y -i rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.1.200 -f segment -segment_time 3 -segment_wrap 2 out_%d.mp4
```

This works as expected and constantly spits out 2 three second files - out_0.mp4 & out_1.mp4. The default FPS of the streaming device is 100. When I add the fps parameter like so:

```
ffmpeg -y -i rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.1.200 -f segment -segment_time 3 -segment_wrap 2 -r 60 out_%d.mp4
```

I see that one or both the files are 4s long and all the frames are the same. When I drop the FPS to 30, the files are at least 8s long.

What am I doing wrong? How can I ensure that the dumped video files are valid and as long as it is specified by `-segment_time`

Answer (score 2):

The segment muxer, by default, only splits at keyframes. Default keyframe interval is around 250.

Add `-g X` where X is `segment_time * fps` to set an appropriate interval.

Comment: `ffmpeg -y -i rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.1.200 -f segment -segment_time 3 -segment_wrap 2 -reset_timestamps 1 -g 150 out_%d.mp4` did not dump out_0.mp4 and out_1.mp4 at 50 fps. They were still at 100 fps.

Comment: You need to retain `-r`